# System freeze after adding noapic acpi=noirq nolapic

Tags: boot, grub2, mouse, internet-connection

I have an issues on which your expert knowledge is required so that I can solve it, here is the scenario:

[Problem was] Sticky mouse after installation!

To solve this issues I did following procedure:

1. `gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub`
2. added `noapic acpi=noirq nolapic` to the end of `CMD_LINUX_Defualt` line
3. ran: `sudo update-grub` and rebooted.

This solved my sticky mouse problem. After that, I installed a mobile broadband, connected it and the connection was established. I opened firefox and probably after 3 or 5 mins, the system froze down. I rebooted it. Now the mobile broadband connection option had disappeared from menu.

The problem is: How do I configure ubuntu so that it does not freezes on using mobile broadband via usb port?

P.S. I have recently switched from Microsoft OS to linux ubuntu

Your kind opinions will highly be appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: And where did you get the bright idea to throw in all those kernel options --- what's the reasoning? It looks like you may have to chose between a sticky but working mouse or no internet at all!

Answer (score 0):

I certainly don't want to sound like a smartass, but the most obvious and easiest thing for you to do IMHO would be to redo your tweaking of grub settings and try a different approach to solve your sticky mouse problem.